# PHP code inside Shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I have this code that displays an mp3 link I have uploaded,

```
    <?php the_field('preview'); ?>
```

But I want to display it inside this shortcode where it says URL OF THE MP3 FILE;

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode("[sc_embed_player fileurl="URL OF THE MP3 FILE"]"); ?>
```

I'm having issues on doing this. Basically the short code is a play button and the the_field preview displays the mp3 link that the play button needs in order to play the mp3 link.

Answer (score 1):

`get_field` returns a value, whereas `the_field` echos it. You need the value to be returned into your shortcode string so `do_shortcode()` can read and process it. Also you need to escape the double quotes or use single quotes on `fileurl= ""`

So, assuming `preview` is just the URL (and not a full HTML link) - I think the following should work:

```
<?= do_shortcode("[sc_embed_player fileurl='".get_field('preview')."']"); ?>
```

*(If `preview` is a HTML link, just paste it in your original post, comment on this answer, and I'll update my answer).*

Hope this helps.